# Label text gets updated but the visual doesnt

Tags: python, customtkinter

```
def update_timers(stop_event1):
    global show_boss_label
    while not stop_event1.is_set():
        for index, boss in enumerate(timers):
            if show_boss.get() == "on":
                show_boss_label = show_bosses_list[index]
            boss_var = boss_vars[index]

            timer = seconds_to_hms(seconds_until_timestamp(boss["time"]))
            boss_var.set(timer)
            if show_boss.get() == "on":
                show_boss_label.configure(text=boss["name"]+" "+timer)
        time.sleep(1)
        frame.update_idletasks()

def switch_to_manual():
    global manual_mode, thread3_running, thread3
    manual_mode = not manual_mode
    if not manual_mode:
        manual_btn.configure(text="Авто")
        show_boss.place(x=130, y=313)
    else:
        manual_btn.configure(text="Вручную")
        show_boss.place(x=150, y=313)

    for index, boss in enumerate(timers):
        row = index // bosses_per_row
        col = index % bosses_per_row

        boss_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(timers_frame, width=boss_frame_width, height=boss_frame_height,
                                            fg_color="#333333")
        boss_frame.place(x=10 + col * (boss_frame_width + 10), y=10 + row * (boss_frame_height + 10))

        boss_name = boss["name"]
        boss_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=boss_frame, text=boss_name)
        boss_label.place(x=boss_frame_width // 2, y=5, anchor="n")

        if manual_mode:
            formatted_time = countdown_to_timestamp(boss["time"])
            boss_var = customtkinter.StringVar()
            boss_var.set(formatted_time)
            boss_timer = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=boss_frame, textvariable=boss_var)
            boss_timer.place(x=30, y=28)
            boss_labels.append(boss_timer)
            boss_vars.append(boss_var)
        else:
            boss_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=boss_frame, width=65, height=15)
            boss_entry.insert(0, countdown_to_timestamp(boss["time"]))
            boss_entry.place(x=20, y=28)
            boss_entries.append(boss_entry)

        boss_location = boss["mine"]
        boss_location_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=boss_frame, text=boss_location)
        boss_location_label.place(x=25, y=50)
```

I dont know why but the `show_boss_label` gets updated but the `boss_label` doesnt and also i have another function to display the license expiration time and it updates normally.

The function needs to update the timers

[image: program visual]

Comment: The question unformatted sorry guys

Comment: [Formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I don't see any code that updates `boss_label`. Each time you call `switch_to_manual()` it creates a new `boss_label` element, it doesn't update an existing element.